# Laravel User has only one plan, access that plan with relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

My user Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','plan_id', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function plan()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Plan');
    }
}
```

And i have `plan_id` in user table as a foreign key, that refers to the id in `plan` table.

When i accesss, `User::with('plan')->get();` i cant get plan, what did i miss?

Comment: share `Plan` model also ?

Comment: What does "I cant get plan" mean?

Comment: what this return User::with('plan')->get();. empty object or error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have plan_id in user table as a foreign key, that refers to the id in plan table.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','plan_id', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plan');
    }
}
```

Comment: Use belongsTo relationship public function plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Plan');
    }

Answer (score 0):

in your user model :

```
public function plan()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Plan','user_id','id');
}
```

in your controller :

```
$users=User::with('plan')->get();
```